# How do I detect if Samsung Pay or Google Pay are the default Payment apps?

Tags: android, nfc, default, google-pay, samsung-pay

I'm looking for a way to understand if the user is using Samsung Pay or Google Pay as the default payment app.

Reading from [Tap and Pay documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce#CheckIfDefault), you can use

```
override suspend fun isDefaultWallet(packageName: String, fullClassName: String): Boolean {
        val nfcManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE) as NfcManager
        val emulation = CardEmulation.getInstance(nfcManager.defaultAdapter)
        val componentName = ComponentName(packageName, fullClassName)
        return emulation.isDefaultServiceForCategory(componentName, CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT)
}
```

For Google Pay:

- package name: `com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel`
- class name: `com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.hce.service.TpHceService`

What are the values for Samsung Pay?

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung Pay:

- package name: `com.samsung.android.spayfw`
- class name: `com.samsung.android.spayfw.core.hce.SPayHCEService`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private boolean isGoogleWalletDefaultPaymentMethod(){
    NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
    CardEmulation cardEmulation = CardEmulation.getInstance(manager.getDefaultAdapter());
    if (cardEmulation.getDescriptionForPreferredPaymentService().equals("Google Pay"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Plus if you want to know the package name of Samsung pay it's this: **com.samsung.android.spay**